# Handling TCP when handshake is not finished in .NET

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Suppose I have a running .NET server with a `TcpListener` server accepting clients. How should I handle non responding clients?

`NetworkStream` has the `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` that seem very useful, and alternatively you could keep your own timer and reset it as progress is made in the session.

But of those seem to rely on an already established tcp connection - what about the case when the handshake connection is not actually finalized? Is there a way to deal with this using the `TcpListener` or `TcpClient` class? What should I set to make sure that connections with an unfinished handshake are stopped, if I don't want such connections to exist for more than a few seconds?

I can't find clear information on whether perhaps setting a timeout for the listener socket will handle this. I'm also not sure whether `AcceptTcpClient` will actually stop blocking if the handshake is not finished, or whether `BeginAcceptTcpClient` is guaranteed to run its callback for tcp connections that do not get a full handshake. It doesn't look like it, given that the callback is only called after the operation actually finished.

Essentially, I would like to know whether there is some way to get notified when any tcp syn packet is received on the listening port - even when the handshake has not yet been finished.

Alternatively, it seems like this can only be handled via settings OS settings, like the NetTCPIP powershell settings on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to handle client request timeout.
one of them is [Send timeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendtimeout?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcpclient-sendtimeout) which you can use to set how long the client requests should be alive after being sent.Also [ConnectAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcpclient-connectasync(system-string-system-int32-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) function has the CanslationToken parameter which is so useful.
If you don't want to use [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-6.0) and you rather [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-6.0), there are also many ways to do that like [Send timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendtimeout?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-socket-sendtimeout) or [Receive timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-socket-receivetimeout)
but I think [CanclationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) is more common among the code samples I have seen which you can pass in all the [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-6.0) functions like [ConnectAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.connectasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-sockettaskextensions-connectasync(system-net-sockets-socket-system-net-endpoint-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) or [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.sendasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-sockettaskextensions-sendasync(system-net-sockets-socket-system-readonlymemory((system-byte))-system-net-sockets-socketflags-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) etc.